# Pandas read_csv with JIT Bodo is slower than regular Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying out [Bodo](https://docs.bodo.ai/2022.5/) to speed up certain Pandas operations, the first being `pd.read_csv(...)`. Bodo requires the compatible pandas code to be in a separate function, separate from non-Bodo compatible code. For example, this is my code:

**With Bodo:**

```
import bodo

@bodo.jit
def loadDataFileWithJIT(filePath):
    df = pd.read_csv(filePath, header=0, sep="\t", names=["patid", "eventdate", "prodcode", "consid", "issueseq"],
                       usecols=[0, 1, 3, 4, 12],
                       dtype={"patid": "str", "eventdate": "str", "prodcode": "str", "consid": "str", "issueseq": "str"},
                       low_memory=False)
    return df
```

Over 5 files I see these times:

- 14.24 <--- first time, so this is when JIT compiles
- 9.67
- 10.72
- 9.51
- 9.42

**Without Bodo** (the function decorator and import statement have been removed... nothing else has changed):

- 4.66
- 4.68
- 4.59
- 4.61
- 4.60

Each file is approximately 170MB.

### Update

Having spoken with the authors of Bodo I need to be running Python from `mpiexec -n` # (where # is number of cores > 1) if I'm to see a speed up.

Comment: maybe send this to authors of bodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: speeding up I/O operations requires parallelism. You'd need to use mpiexec with more than one process.

Bodo currently reuses pandas read_csv under the hood to ensure full compatibility. JIT compilation enables parallelism, but doesn’t improve anything on a single core (and in fact has some overhead as you are observing).

You can use ipyparallel to launch and manage Bodo/MPI processes within a single process:
https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel

Bodo Slack discussion:
https://bodocommunity.slack.com/archives/C01KRTQ1KDY/p1661704632557289